# I have a text field, who's value is being HTML encoded every time the value gets saved.... C# ASP.NET Web Forms ADO.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ado.net, html-encode

So there are text field and text area web form controls, which are being HTML encoded. A string like "alert(‘XSS’)" would be HTML encoded and look like this "<script>alert(‘XSS’)</script>"... the problem with that is the next time that value is processed via a form control that does not allow HTML, it will encode this encoded string yet again this time and turn the leading < into &lt;

```
namespace EncodingExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // every single time a form is saved, any text fields which have
            // previously encoded fields (meaning they had HTML in them before)
            // will be encoded again. &gt; becomes &amp;gt; on the second pass...

            string example = "<script>alert(‘XSS’)</script>";
            Console.WriteLine("Original screen input by malicious user: " + example);

            var encodedOnce = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(example);
            Console.WriteLine("Original string encoded once: " + encodedOnce);
            var encodedAgain = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(encodedOnce);
            Console.WriteLine("Original string encoded a second time: " + encodedAgain);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I prevent the < (which is the < character) from being messed with on subsequent processing?

Should I be decoding this on page load (this is a legacy ASP.NET web forms app)? Does encoding the content upon posting, and decoding it upon page load still block XSS attacks?

What is considered, if any, safe HTML that can somehow get "past" the HttpUtility.HtmlEncode method. That would be ideal, if say for example, styling were still allowed to be applied via HTML input in a text control. Is this possible?

Comment: We'll need to see a [mcve].

Comment: Demo code added

In short, characters like the < are being Html encoded as &gt; and stored in the DB. Then when an object is loaded, and a text field is being populated with the string that contains the newly encoded  string with &gt; in it..... upon being saved a second time the HttpUtility.Encode is now encoding the & in the &gt; and will continue doing this indefinitly. It gets ugly...... &amp;amp;amp;&amp; and so on....

How do you avoid the original conversion from < to &gt; from being HTML encoded any further on subsequent saves (which run the HTML encoding logic)?

Comment: Why are you calling `HtmlEncode` (before saving it to the database) **at all**? You should stop doing that.

Comment: Any suggestions then? The reason in doing so is to prevent XSS attacks by not allowing HTML input into the text area. I suppose if that is the ask, I could just use a regex to only allow standard characters?

Comment: Encoding is something that should be done when outputting (i.e. rendering to the screen). It shouldn't be done before storing it in the database...